# Problemas con la migración de mi sitio web montado con CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Estoy realizando la migración de un sitio web montado con CodeIgniter de un servicio de hosting gestionado con panel plesk a otro hosting gestionado con cPanel.

El sitio web en el alojamiento original funciona sin problemas pero al realizar la migración el navegador me devuelve el siguiente error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

El proceso que he seguido para realizar la migración es el siguiente:
- Descarga de archivos por FTP del alojamiento original.
- Subida de los datos al nuevo servidor.
- Exportación e importación de la base de datos vinculada al sitio.
- Configuración del archivo config.php y database.php con los datos del nuevo hosting.

Hablando con el proveedor del nuevo alojamiento me comentan que es una versión antigua de CodeIgniter y puede haber incompatibilidades entre las versiones de php del servidor.

Decir que no he desarrollado el sitio desde el principio y tengo conocimientos básicos de PHP

Espero que alguien me pueda dar alguna pista sobre lo que puedo hacer para solucionar esto.
Muchas gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Comment: Necesitas verificar cual es el controlador principal y de ahí ver si ese controlador no está haciendo múltiples redirecciones, checa bien el archivo routes que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta config.

Answer (score 0):

si es por tema de que tengas una versión antigua de Codeigniter, es cierto que pueda dar problemas con servidores con PHP más actuales (> v7).

En la página web de codeigniter, hay una guía para hacer el upgrading de las versiones, puedes verlo aquí:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html

Eso sí, tendrás que ver qué versión de CI tienes actualmente e ir paso a paso subiendo una versión hasta que alcances una que funcione en tu servidor php.

También puede ser que el archivo .htaccess no esté bien configurado. Busca una configuración válida en la red y aplícala a tu proyecto. Prueba con algo así:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101031/codeigniter-on-localhost-too-many-redirects?rq=1